Why does the vote count on the profile page differ from that on the votes page?
For example, here is my count on upvotes from the profile page:



However when I open the link that says "View all (number) votes",
this is what I get for Upvotes:



That is a difference of 99 votes, multiple times the number of votes that I can even cast in a day. Where does this difference come from, and which number is the correct number here?

You’ve upvoted 99 deleted posts.
“Votes cast”  on the summary tab was updated to count deleted posts, however, they are not included in the count on the votes activity tab. So you upvoted 99 posts that are currently deleted.

Thank you, that perfectly explains it. I don't think I have to wait for a day around here on meta to accept it?

You don’t have to wait a day anywhere. The idea behind waiting on the main site is to indicate that you are still considering other answers. Seeing an accepted answer already there might discourage a potential answerer from leaving an answer if they believe the question is already settled in your mind. This is why we encourage new users to wait - it may lead to them getting an even better answer.
